# How to zip up files of same prefix in python?

Tags: python

If I have a directory "C:\Files" that contains a bunch of files:

A_File1
A_File2
B_File1
B_File2

What is the best way to iterate through the files to zip up any file with the same prefix into a single zip file? For instance, output would be "A.zip" and "B.zip" and their associated files.

I know how to iterate through the files:

```
for item in os.listdir("C:\FILES"):
```

But I do not know what the best way to zip up the files is or if there is some python library that helps with that.

Comment: http://effbot.org/librarybook/zipfile.htm

Comment: What constitues a common prefix?  Just the characters before the underscore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that `C:\FILES\` contains only files that you want to compress, and each file is in the format `PREFIX_*`.

```
import glob, os
import zipfile
import defaultdict

# We organize the file names in a dict to
# make writing out the zip files easier

d = defaultdict(list)

for fname in glob.glob(r'C:\FILES\*'):
   d[fname.split('_')[0]].append(fname)

# Now we go through each file by letter
for letter in d:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(letter+'.zip','w') as f:
        for filename in d[letter]:
            f.write(filename, os.path.basename(filename), zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the glob module from the standard library, instead of os.listdir:

```
from glob import glob

for file in glob("C:\\FILES\\A_File*"):
    ...
```

(If you are using backslashes to separate dirs, use two, because a single one is a escape character in Python strings)

Comment: Or you can use raw strings `r'C:\FILES\A_File'`

Comment: Or you can use `'C:/FILES/A_File'`

Answer (score 0):

```
for fname in glob.glob('c:\files\A_*'):
    print fname
```